# how to a add a counter variable (not globally)

Tags: node.js

I want to make a counter variable which keeps incrementing when something happens in a function, but not declare it globally in nodeJS

This is what I have:

```
var ctr = 0;
function myCTR(){
    if(some condition){
        //something happens
        ctr++;
    }else{
        //nothing
}
```

Comment: What is your problem or question? Side note: you do not need if block neither else when you don't do anything in it. Just write `if (something) ctr++`

Comment: i mean there are more conditions, but I just want to know how to declare the ctr variable internally rather than globally.

Comment: `ctr` is in module scope. It's not a global.

Comment: what is a module scope?

Comment: If you add `'use strict'` to the top of your file, it will prevent to use global variables. (It will throw an error when you running your script) Otherwise you can declare global variable if you omit the `[let|const|var]` keywords before them eg.: `foo = 5` the `foo` is global. But in strict mode your script will throw.

Comment: ah I understand! thanks! @lependu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctr` variable isn't a global, unless it's assigned as `global.ctr = ...`. It's located in module scope.

Node.js is based on [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (CommonJS modules for .js scripts and ES for .mjs scripts). The code that is evaluated is evaluated in module scope.

In case of CommonJS module a script is evaluated inside [module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) function, i.e.

```
var ctr = 0;
...
```

script is in fact

```
function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  var ctr = 0;
  ...
}
```

`ctr` variable is local to module function and cannot leak to global scope.